# GWT refactoring: classes, modules, rename the whole project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, refactoring

I am writing here because of desperation caused by refactoring a GWT project.

*My first try*:
 After I read all the praises of the refactoring tool from Eclipse ( I am using it as IDE) I simply right clicked on a module ( what a fool i was ) and use the refactoring option. My project became unusable.

First Conclusion: 
 Found out that I need to start with the classes and then go up and refactor a module at a time.

*Second try:* 
 Refactored some classes, worked fine until I messed something related to a ui.xml file. Project unusable!

Second Conclusion:
 Be careful at the ui.xml files!

*Third try:* 
 Went pretty well, but I got ahead of myself and tried to remove some comments or replace class names in comments. Predictable result : project unusable!

Third Conclusion: 
 Try again!

Forth try: 
 Fail!

Fifth try:
 Fail!

You get the picture.

Can someone experienced with GWT please offer some guidelines about the mystical realm of refactoring?

Comment: Anyone? No GWT guru's around?

Answer (score 1):

GWT has some rules based on naming conventions (e.g. the two interfaces for GWT-RPC, the `*.ui.xml` files and the class that uses them through `UiBinder`, the files related to `ClientBundle` or `ImageBundle` methods, the `*.properties` files for I18N), so failing to respect them when renaming/moving one class/file will break it.

GWT also sometimes references classes by name in non-Java files (`@eval` in the `*.css` of a `CssResource`, or in `*.ui.xml` files), non-Java portions of classes (JSNI) or string literals (e.g. in `@ProxyForName` and `@ServiceName`). Failing to update them all will break the build.

Because a tool makes it easy to refactor does not mean you should let it do it blindly: it's just a tool, you have to understand what it does and double-check it (hint: check the box in Eclipse that forces a *preview* before applying the refactoring) so it doesn't do too much or too few.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on when is the proper time to rebuild the project and check if something is broken?
For example : refactor all the classes from a module and rebuild etc...